# Why tensor flow give nan instead of number

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1], tf.float32))
# b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1, 1], -1, 1))
hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, w))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(hypothesis* tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train  = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5000):
        #print (sess.run(w))
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={x:x_, y:y_})
    print (sess.run(w))
```

My source code is same as above
I can't understand why result is NAN.
I'm beginner in this tensorflow and machine learning area.
I think my source code is right. Please tell me if there are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing your `x_` values, it is difficult to know for certain. But an educated guess is the `tf.log` op you are using received zero or negative inputs. So instead of

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(hypothesis* tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

Try something like

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(hypothesis* tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y, 1e-8, 1.0)), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

Also worth pointing out is that as of version 1.0.0-alpha TensorFlow has a specialized debugger that helps diagnosing this kind of issues, among others. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/debugger/

To try it out, after your line `sess.run(init)` add.

```
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
sess.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)
```

In the command-line interface that shows up on the next `sess.run` call.

```
tfdbg> run -f has_inf_or_nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying a simple logistic regression but the variables are all mixed up.

First, the cross entropy must be:

```
y*tf.log(hypothesis)
```

not the other way around. Second, `y` must sampled from your data labels - something that you are not doing. `x_` and `y_` are missing. It is hard to debug without correcting all these two issues.